# Show contents of the Windows clipboard

Tags: windows, clipboard

How can I see what the Windows clipboard currently contains without using the paste operation?

I don't want the "pasted-to" application to perform any actions on the clipboard (for example, formatting text and converting).

Is there a tool which shows the clipboard's objects and their format (CF_BITMAP, CF_TEXT, etc.) and content (in simple bytes for example)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a list of clipboard manager tools at Wikipedia:
*[Clipboard manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipboard_manager)*

[ClipX](http://bluemars.org/clipx/) allows you to view a log of previous clipboard entries by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.

Answer (score 7):

NirSoft offers a free “[Inside Clipboard](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/inside_clipboard.html)” utility which allows you to see the raw clipboard contents and different formats. It’s close to what you would see with a programmatic API but with a nice GUI. Its GUI includes hex view. It also allows data to be exported and allows saving a snapshot to a `.clp` file which it can open and allow you to examine later.

If you need to see things at the level of the programmatic API to quick check things without writing a program yourself, I recommend this tool.

Answer (score 4):

If using .NET you can query the [Clipboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.clipboard) object.

Answer (score 0):

To display the format tags, I recommend **winclip** in Diomidis Spinellis' '**outwit**' package at https://www.spinellis.gr/sw/outwit/

*Outwit is a suite of tools based on the Unix tool design principles allowing the processing of Windows application data with sophisticated data manipulation pipelines. The outwit tools offer access to the Windows clipboard, the registry, the event log, relational databases, document properties, and shell links.*

Note:  This is a command line tool, unlike Nir Sofer's **InsideClipboard**.

Answer (score -1):

How about the regular old Clipbrd.exe clipboard viewer from Windows XP?

That'll still run on Windows Vista and Windows 7, IIRC.

Comment: For Windows 7 and newer OSes, the problem is finding a reliable download of it.

Answer (score -9):

1. Select run from the start menu.
2. Enter "clipbrd.exe" in it.

Then you can see the clipboard items in the Windows systems.

Comment: Not present anymore in Windows 8

Comment: Also not present in Windows 7.

Comment: Also not present in Windows 10

Comment: Also not present in Windows Server 2012

Comment: Information out of date, better remove this comment please