# How does the clipboard work in Windows?

Tags: windows, clipboard

What is its data structure? Is it XML-based? How can it distinguish between different content types, for example text, image, files etc.?

Answer (score 10):

It is a system wide bit bucket, which means it just holds a sequence of bytes and an integer value (a windows atom) which describes it's format - but does not ensure that the byte sequence is really this format.

The only feature other then this is that an application can decide if it wants the system to store the byte sequence or if the application keeps the data itself and only provide it when someone is requesting it.

So as you see it is an API and not a data structure.

Comment: Not true. The clipboard can hold data in several different formats at once.

Comment: You are right i forgot about this. 

So we can see it as dictionary with the format integer number as the hash key and sequences of bytes as values.

Comment: Would you suggest some proper way to analyse clipboard contents? I'd like to understand what's its structure after copying something from a spreadsheet (like LibreOffice) to understand if the structure can be replicated with handsontable (for instance, to be able to copy and paste text colors)

Comment: Ok, nevermind, looks like I just have to try some clipboard managers (according to answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667179/show-contents-of-the-windows-clipboard)